# How to monitor packet sent by ping?

Tags: ping, wireshark, tcpdump, packet-analyzer, libpcap

I just want to capture the packets sent by ping. I know there are tcpdump, but it doesn't just capture the packets for a single program. So is there a way to just capture the packet for a single program? Thanks.

Comment: Ping packets use ICMP (Internet Control Message Protocol) not IP.

Comment: So what can be used to monitor ICMPs?

Comment: Read `man tcpdump`. In the "`Examples`" section there's a way to monitor all ICMP except ping.

Comment: What exactly do you want to capture about these packets? If you're wanting to see what the ping command is writing to the network you can do it with ```strace```, e.g. ```strace -f -e trace=network ping www.google.com```